# What is the time complexity of this recursion with memoization code?

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

```
public class Solution {
    public boolean wordBreak(String s, List<String> wordDict) {
        return wordBreakMemo(s, new HashSet<>(wordDict), 0, new Boolean[s.length()]);
    }

    // a function that will compute the answer for every given state
    private boolean wordBreakMemo(String s, Set<String> wordDict, int start, Boolean[] memo) {
        //base case: null is true
        if (start == s.length()) {
            return true;
        }
        //avoid recomputation
        if (memo[start] != null) {
            return memo[start];
        }
        for (int end = start + 1; end <= s.length(); end++) {
            //recurrence relation 
            //dp[start] = set.contains(substring(start,end)) && dp[end]
            if (wordDict.contains(s.substring(start, end)) && wordBreakMemo(s, wordDict, end, memo)) {
                return memo[start] = true;
            }
        }
        return memo[start] = false;
    }
}
```

This is a leetcode (139.word break) solution using recursion with memoization.
The editorial said the time complexity is `O(n^3)`, where n is the length of input string.
I don't get it, can someone please shed light on this, thanks.

Edit:
My thought: We have n possible starting positions, and for each starting position, a substring can end at any positions from the starting position to the end of the string. On average, we have (n + 1) / 2 ending positions for each starting position, so we have n(n + 1)/2 possible substrings which is O(n^2). And for every recursion, we invoke **.substring()** which is O(n), then the total time comlexity if O(n^3).